# Nested query in Hive not working: ParesException

Tags: sql, database, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want the entire query to run for each value returned by the sub-query in where clause. I am unable to figure out what i am doing wrong here. Please help?

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.* 
FROM table1 a, table2 b, table3 c
WHERE a.val1 = ( select val1 from table1 )
AND a.val2 = b.val3
AND a.val4 = c.val5;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`in` instead of `=`

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.* 
FROM table1 a, table2 b, table3 c
WHERE a.val1 in ( select val1 from table1 )
AND a.val2 = b.val3
AND a.val4 = c.val5;
```